# Fluent NHibernate Mapping not on PK Field

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, orm

I have the following tables and cannot edit their structure...

```
Person
------
Id PK
Code
Name

Order
-----
Id PK
Person_Code
OrderDetails
```

Now in my Person class I want to have a list of Orders for that person, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about setting up the mapping in fluent nhibernate to match on the Code column rather than the ID.  There is no foreign key constraint and I am unable to change the database to use the keys.  Something like this is what I require, but can;t seem to figure out the mapping.

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; private set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your column with the KeyColumn method. It should work regardless of existence of a foreign key constraint.

```
class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        HasMany(p => p.Order)
            .KeyColumn("Person_Code")
            .PropertyRef("Code");
    }
}
```

PropertyRef method is available from [rev 614](http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads) so you may need to update the fluent nhibernate version.

Comment: But how does it know which column in the Person table it should compare that too?

Comment: I missed that the first time, sorry. I updated the answer to reflect your issue.

Comment: I think I must be using an old version of the Fluent lib, as I'm not getting the PropertyRef method.  Will try updating.

Comment: Can anyone offer any help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840521/fluent-nhibernate-mapping-on-multiple-non-pk-fields ?