# Fluent NHibernate mapping on multiple non-PK fields

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a situation similar to that described in [Fluent NHibernate Mapping not on PK Field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2192952/326110)

However, the relationship between my tables is described by multiple non-primary key columns.
Imagine Chris Meek's situation but where a `Person` has a `JobType` and a `Code` that, together, *should* (sorry, it's a legacy database) uniquely describe a `Person`

```
Person
------
Id PK
JobType
Code
Name

Order
-----
Id PK
Person_JobType
Person_Code
OrderDetails
```

Serhat Özgel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2193013/326110) describes using `PropertyRef`, but I can't find a way to do that individually for multiple columns. I've tried similar to

```
class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        HasMany(p => p.Order)
            .KeyColumns.Add("Person_JobType")
            .PropertyRef("JobType")
            .KeyColumns.Add("Person_Code")
            .PropertyRef("Code")
    }
}
```

But this obviously doesn't work, since `KeyColumns.Add()` returns another `OneToManyPart` so `PropertyRef()` isn't being run against the individual column being added. The second `PropertyRef()` simply overwrites the first one, and I get the following error:

```
NHibernate.MappingException : collection foreign key mapping
has wrong number of columns: MyApp.Person.Order type: Int32
```

I've looked at the various overloads of KeyColumns.Add(),

```
public TParent Add(string name)
public TParent Add(params string[] names)
public TParent Add(string columnName, Action<ColumnPart> customColumnMapping)
public TParent Add(ColumnMapping column)
```

Specifically the last two, but couldn't find any way to set `PropertyRef` individually level for each column :(
Is there a way to do that? Am I going about this the wrong way entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using hbm.xml and FluentNHibernate it is possible with a trick

```
class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Map(_ => JobTypeAndCode)
            .Columns.Add("Person_JobType", "Person_Code")
            .ReadOnly()
            .LazyLoad() // optional: prevent loading the Columns twice
            .Access.None();

        HasMany(p => p.Orders)
            .KeyColumns.Add("Person_JobType", "Person_Code")
            .PropertyRef("JobTypeAndCode")
    }

    private object JobTypeAndCode { get; set; } // FakeProperty
}
```

Note: i never got this to work using NHibernate MappingByCode

Comment: Wow, nice. What I ended up doing for this was not having an NHibernate mapping between these classes, and just extracting the values and throwing them back at the other class's repository to get the appropriate records when necessary - rather ugly. I wish I knew your trick last week :)

Comment: This is the error I got while trying this approach (could not get past it): any mappings may not form part of a property-ref

Comment: @VishalKumar better ask a question and post some code? Looks like the property for the propertyref is a referenceAny instead of Map

Comment: @firo answer works with one major drawback. The original type of the columns is corrupted in the parent table. Does anyone have an idea how it can be fixed?

Comment: @LeoY what means corrupted? I think i tested this and it worked.

Comment: @firo It means that when I map my properties of type int and then use this technique on them, the DB schema created with these field types as varbinary(max). I will try to create a schema using SQL DDL and use the mapping only for queries and let you know if it is working.